# bounty not to the chosen one

Tags: discussion, answers, bounties

is it possible to award a bounty to the different answer, not the chosen one ?

(e.g. i'd like to choose the best useful solution, which however does not completely follow the question conditions, and the bounty i'd like to give to the answer, whoch sompletely answers the question, but is complicated and rather theoretical, than usable)

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, the bounty isn't tied to the accepted answer anymore, see the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: thanks. FAQ does not say specifically, if they are tied..

Comment: yeh, I don't think they've completely fixed the wording yet, I have another [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56782/faq-bounty-language-still-mentions-accept) out on that.